# How to put a container on top of an image on Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

[image]

Sorry for the bad sketch, but I just wanted to make my idea clearer, so let's say I have an image, (black rectangle), and over this picture I want to have a container (yellow rounded rectangle), and between the two I want to have a third container (white), I also don't want the parts of the image outside of the yellow frame to appear

Comment: Use stack widget https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is Stack.
Stack let you lay out widgets above each other.
So for example in your case you would create something like this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Image.asset('example'),
    Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.white,
    )
  ],
)
```

of course with specific decoration for the containers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put `Container()` in center of an image then use below code :

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Image.asset(...),
    Positioned.fill(
      child : Container(...),
    ),
])
```

Or, you can give value of top, bottom, left and right in `Positioned()` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Container Box Decoration Property for background image and place your inner widget in child

```
Container(
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage( //TODO: Place your image here
                          'assets/dummy/projects_dummy.webp',
                        ),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                child: InnerChildWidget() //Add your inner child here
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 70,
                height: 70,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 50,
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.yellow,
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 30,
                height: 30,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                "assets/Doctor1.svg",
                height: 10,
                width: 10,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/opppw.png
```